# Thread only runs once - Java - Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

So I'm working on a project. I have an Arduino robot that communicates with an app via Bluetooth. Essentially the Arduino is a battle bot equipped with various sensors. When the robot recognizes that it has been shot (via IR codes). It sends a message to the app so that its health can be decremented. (Arduino sends lower case 'h' with a '#' as a delimiter to signal the end of the message. Now I'm trying to run a thread to listen for the data and when a character ('h') or any other character is received on the app it is dealt with and the proper function is called. Now my problem is that my function can only be called once. I'm new to threads and having a hard time understanding why it does not resume the thread and continue listening for more characters.

Here is the thread listening for data. Its a little messy as I have some tracer code to try and find the issue

```
void beginListenForData(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 35; //ASCII for #
    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker){

                try{
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                    //InputStream mmInputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
                    //inTest.setText("INPUT: " + bytesAvailable);
                    if(bytesAvailable>0){
                        //inTest.setText("Bytes Available");
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");

                                readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {

                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        /*
                                        Possible messages from arduino
                                            r = arduino ready
                                            k = Robot has tilted and is dead
                                            h = robot has been shot
                                        */


                                        inTest.setText("Received: " + data + "\n" +"Times shot: " + timesShot);

                                        if(data.equals("h")){
                                            //workerThread.interrupt();

                                            System.out.println("ROBOT HAS BEEN SHOT");
                                            robo1.takeDamage(10);
                                            System.out.println("ROBOT HAS CALLED DAMAGE METHOD");
                                        }

                                        //if(data.equals("k")){
                                        //  msg("ROBOT FLIPPED!");
                                        //}


                                    }

                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    msg("IEXCEPTION TRIGGER");
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    msg("WorkerThread Start");
    workerThread.start();
}
```

Also here is my takeDamage method that also has some tracer code in there and shows some of the things I have tried to resolve the issue.

```
       private void takeDamage(int dmg){
        ROBOT_HEALTH -= dmg;
        msg("Robot Shot");
        timesShot++;
        System.out.println("ROBOT IS TAKING DAMAGE");
        inTest.setText("Times shot: " + timesShot + "\n Robot Health: " +  ROBOT_HEALTH);

        //workerThread.start();
        //msg("Robot Health" + robo1.getHealth() + "\n");
        //if(this.getHealth() <= 0){
         //   //GAME OVER ROBOT DEAD
          //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ROBOT DEAD",
          //          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //}
    }
```

TLDR; Why does the thread not continue to listen for data after a method call. If not method is called the handler will keep looping indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really try this code but I think you get the idea. With `start()` you start the Thread and with `stop()` you interrupt it. The `Runnable` implements a while loop that can possibly run forever ;) But I guess you wanne stop it at some point. Hope this helps!

```
private Thread thread;    

public void start() {
    if (thread != null) return;
    thread = new Thread(new ListenerRunnable());
    thread.start();
}

public void stop() {
    if (thread == null) return;
    thread.interrupt();
    thread = null;
}

private static class ListenerRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {

                // !!! Here goes your code to listen !!!

            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That got me on the right track and clears things up a little. I also just called my beginListenForData() method in the takeDamage method and that also restarts the thread. I'm not sure if its the most efficient or proper way but it works!

Comment: @user3525633 happy to be of help ;)